# Django: sending a POST request with Javascript, but then displaying an updated page rather than the old one

Tags: javascript, python, django, post

I have an input that fires a onclick calling a javascript function in my main template:

```
 <div class="removeTagElementChildDiv">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="image" name="deleteTagImage" class="deleteTagImage" src="{% static 'images/deleteTag.png' %}" width = "10" height = "10" onclick="return removeTag(this.parentElement)">
            </div>
```

This calls this method:

```
 function removeTag(removeSymbolDivForTagToRemove)
    {
        tagElement = removeSymbolDivForTagToRemove.parentElement
        tagValue = tagElement.querySelector('button[name="tagInTagsMenu"]').value
        console.log(tagValue)
        if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the, ${tagValue}, tag`))
        {
            return test(tagValue)      
        }
    }
```

Where the test method makes a POST request to one of my specified urls in urls.py:

```
function test(tagValue)
{
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
    fetch('deleteTag', {
    method: 'POST',
    action: 'deleteTag',
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
    },
    body: tagValue
})
}
```

This method deletes the specific tag from the post request, and redirects to the main page:

```
def deleteTag(request):
    tagName = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    Tag.objects.filter(name=tagName).delete()
    tagsFromModel = Tag.objects.all()
    for tag in tags: 
        if util.findTagByTagName(tag.name,tagsFromModel) == None: #if the tag from the original list is not in the model, it has been deleted
            tags.remove(tag)
    
    loadTagsFromModel()
    print("end of delete tag method")
    return(redirect("/"))

def main(request):
    now = datetime.now()

    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    loadTagsFromModel()
    context = {'myTags':tags,'time':time}
    print("tags in main",len(tags)) 
    #problemet er, at den stadig displayer den gamle index.html når man sletter et tag
    return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

All this works fine, and the data is correctly updated in the tag list.
However, through debugging (with the time) I discovered that even though I call:

```
return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

The new page that is displayed is still the old index.html, where the tag has not been deleted.
It is only if I refresh the page or perform some other actions on the page (actions that directly redirect through Django's url.py) that the new index.html is displayed.

I suppose that it is something about the javascript functions that does not return properly, and thus still renders the old index.html, but I have no idea how I am supposed to *replace* the old template with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I added a form to the input in the index.html. I am not sure why this works seeing as I am already making a POST request in javascript.

If anyone could explain why it works, I would still appreciate it.

Comment: Does it work without refreshing the page or it's working like traditional form POST submission?

Comment: I don't have to manually refresh if that is what you are saying, but the page does get refreshed when the POST submission happens.

Comment: But that is probably just because i always redirect to my index page after all actions on the page